# How to disable buttons in Fiori UI5 app using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am not an expert in scripting languages. I am trying to hide buttons in SAP Fiori app, by debugging in Mozilla browser using the "Inspect element" tool. If I delete the HTML code, the button is deleted but I want to achieve this behavior through code in the SAP Fiori app. Please, could you guide me how to achieve this in SAP Fiori (UI5) app?

#### Screenshot of HTML

[image]

Comment: What is this about?? Are you developing a free-style UI5 app? Or a Fiori Element app with OData annotations? Is the app a standard Fiori app made by SAP? The question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide a button, you might delete the button in the corresponding XML view.
Another possibility might be, to use the “visible”-property of the button control.

Answer (score 0):

In your case with the App maintain Personal Data you can remove the create record button via backend customizing. There is no need to modify or extend the Fiori app. The customizing view in the backend system is V_T7XSSPERSUBTY.